# Create object with multiple relations in graphene django

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

Hi guys I have the following models in my project

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    # set custom manager
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField("users.User", verbose_name=_("customer user account"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # general info
    first_name = models.CharField(_('customer first name'), max_length=100, help_text='customer first name')
    last_name = models.CharField(_('customer last name'), max_length=100, help_text='customer last name')

    # addresses info
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField('users.address', verbose_name=_('customer addresses'), related_name='customer_addresses', blank=True)
    default_shipping_address = models.ForeignKey('users.address', verbose_name=_('default shipping address'), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='default_shipping')

class address(models.Model):
    street_1 = models.CharField(_('street address 1'), max_length=250, help_text='street address one')
    street_2 = models.CharField(_('street address 2'), null=True, blank=True, max_length=250, help_text='street address two')

    postal_code = models.IntegerField(_('address zipcode'), help_text='address zipcode')
    city = models.CharField(_('address city'), max_length=100, help_text='address city')
    state = models.CharField(_('address state'), max_length=50, help_text='address state')
    country = models.CharField(_('address country'), max_length=100, help_text='address country')
```

Here is my current implementation of creating a customer mutation

```
class CreateCustomer(graphene.Mutation):
customer = graphene.Field(CustomerType)

    class Arguments:
        email = graphene.String(required=True)
        first_name = graphene.String(required=True)
        last_name = graphene.String(required=True)
        password = graphene.String(required=True)
        phone = graphene.String(required=True)

        street_1 = graphene.String(required=False)
        street_2 = graphene.String(required=False)
        city = graphene.String(required=False)
        state = graphene.String(required=False)
        zipcode = graphene.String(required=False)
        country = graphene.String(required=False)

    def mutate(self, info, email, first_name, last_name, password, phone, street_1=None, street_2=None, city=None, state=None, zipcode=None, country=None):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email=email,
            password = password
        )
        user.save()

        current_customer = customer.objects.create(
            user = user,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            phone_number = phone,
            email_address = email
        )

        if street_1:
            customer_address = address.objects.create(
                street_1 = street_1,
                street_2 = street_2,
                city = city,
                state = state,
                postal_code = zipcode,
                country = country,
            )
            customer_address.save()
            current_customer.addresses.add(customer_address)

        current_customer.save()

    return CreateCustomer(customer=current_customer)
```

Is there a way to simplify this mutation by using other object types? I have types for user, and address so maybe I can use those types to simplify the query, I also would like to be able to add multiple addresses from one mutation

One big problem I have with this implementation is that when I add an address to a customer I need to verify that all fields are present but I can't require it because I would also like to have the whole address optional, so something like adding an address list with a list of mutations would be my best option but I don't knwo how to implement it in graphene, I am new to graphql so it might not be possible at all

Thanks in advance